# How to fix the App_url error in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

i'm using the laravel 5.5 and when i add my virtual host to the .env file this error came up

> The requested URL /password/reset/cafedf0cb3d2a3a0bcfe0c26566233f8afa60901989b8ab48084ec005ed27fe5 was not found on this server

please tell me how can i fix this error...

Comment: Could you add a copy of your env file please?